# How to authenticate in coinbase with OAuth

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, coinbase-api

I have create an OAuth application, it gives me Client ID:xxx Client Secret:yyy
[Redirect URIs](https://www.coinbase.com/oauth), [Authorize URL](https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize), [Access Token URL](https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/token) now what should I do? In coding wise, I am working in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in working with our API!

I think the best explanation of how to work with our API using would is in the documentation on our [developers site](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/authentication#oauth2-authentication).

Take a look at that, and let us know if you have any other questions.

Particularly useful from that page is this sample flow that your app might go through:

```
# Redirect the user to this page
https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_CALLBACK_URL&scope=user+balance

# If the user accepts, they will be redirected to:
YOUR_CALLBACK_URL?code=CODE

# Initiate a POST request to get the access token
https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token&
    grant_type=authorization_code&
    code=CODE&
    redirect_uri=YOUR_CALLBACK_URL&
    client_id=CLIENT_ID&
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET

# Response containing the 'access_token'
{
    "access_token": "...",
    "refresh_token": "...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expire_in": 7200,
    "scope": "universal"
}

# Now you can use the 'access_token' to initiate authenticated requests
https://api.coinbase.com/v1/account/balance?access_token=...

# Response
{
    "amount": "50.00000000",
    "currency": "BTC"
}
```

Comment: Hi John,
Thanks for your response. I dont want in postrequest form, i want to use java functions, so need to know the function to call authentication.

And in getting token , what is the parameter code? what should i mention there.